# how to insert data from an existing table (aggregated data), to another existing table on mysql?

Tags: mysql, insert, aggregate-functions

i'm using mysql,

what i'm trying to do is:

There are two tables:

Invoices_Table:

you can see that the key of this table is the date field,
This field comes in YYYY-DD-MM format, when you can see that for some months, there is More than a single invoice, for example in January there are invoices 1111,1112).

See the INVOICE TABLE screenshot for illustration.

[image: invoce table]

---

AGG_TABLE

This is a table that is currently empty, the key of this table is the date field, which is also in the format
YYYY-DD-MM as in the invoice table.
There are two additional fields, TOTALB, TOTALI, which are in INTEGER format.
See the AGG_TABLE screenshot to illustrate

[image]

My goal is to load the data from the invoice table into the empty table,
So that in the empty table there will be a total of 12 records (one entry for each of the months)
So that the TOTALB column shows:
 the total amount for that month and where INVOICE TYPE=B,
 In the same way,the TOTALI column shows:
 the total amount for the same month ,Where the INVOICE TYPE =I.

See screenshot: RESULT, which illustrates the desired result after loading.

[image]

Note: If there is no record for a particular month (as shown in the screenshot of the invoice table, there are no records for month 11), the AGG_TABLE table still needs a date entry with a sum of 0 for TOTALB, TOTALI columns.
This entry was highlighted in yellow in the RESULT screen

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this

INSERT INTO invoice_agg (inv_date,inv_ag_total)
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(inv_date, "%Y-%m-01"),sum(inv_total) as inv_sum FROM  invoice GROUP BY YEAR(inv_date), MONTH(inv_date) ASC

This query should serve your purpose, if you create a view of this query this will be a much better approach. This query is for mysql database please make necessary adjustments for your flavour of rdbms.

Creating a view is simple

Create view [view name] as [select statement].

You can make a select statement at your view any time to get data

Select * from [view name]

Comment: HI, Thanks for the quick respond, 
I edited my question again, to make it clearer,The result I expect to receive is as shown in the third screenshot RESULT,That is, there should be 3 columns:Month-Year Column,Amount column for Type B,Amount column for type I,For example, in February (02.2013) there are two type I invoices, one for the sum of 500, and the other for the sum of 40, then in the new table in the row of the month of February 02, the amount in the TOTAL I column will be 540.

Comment: Regarding the subject of the VIEW, my ultimate goal is to use the code in a  stored procedure, so reading stored procedure will cause the data from the invoice table to enter the new table. thanks again!